# Data Loss in mySQL Using MEDIUMTEXT and pages

Tags: mysql, concatenation, group-concat

Somehow GROUP_CONCAT is able to round up six "pages" of an article (each stored as TEXT) and toss them into a single MEDIUMTEXT without losing any data, but there are some one-page
articles that are longer than normal (but still obviously fit within the TEXT data type) that lose a significant amount of data. Anyone know what's up?

Original query:

```
SET group_concat_max_len = 16000000;
UPDATE Threads t SET t.Content = (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(a.Content ORDER
BY a.PageID SEPARATOR '<!-- pagebreak -->') FROM MSarticlepages a
WHERE a.ArticleID = t.MSthreadID GROUP BY a.ArticleID);
```

Thanks again for taking the time to guide my ignorant self!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reference manual for MySQL 5.0 (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) states:

> Beginning with MySQL 5.0.19, the type
>   returned by GROUP_CONCAT() is always
>   VARCHAR unless group_concat_max_len is
>   greater than 512, in which case, it
>   returns a BLOB. (Previously, it
>   returned a BLOB with
>   group_concat_max_len  greater than 512
>   only if the query included an ORDER BY
>   clause.)

Based on this data, the return type would be BLOB, not MEDIUMTEXT. Wwould it be possible that the concatenation in total is over 2^16 (65536 bytes), which is the limit for BLOB?